# Concatenated index in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

So basically I'm matching addresses by matching strings within 2 tables

Table B has 5m rows so I really don't want to create new columns for it every time I want to match the addresses

So I thought about creating indexes instead, my current index to match addresses would look like:

```
CREATE INDEX matchingcol_idx  ON tableB USING btree (sub_building_name || ', ' || building_name )
```

However this does not work, it doesn't accept the concatenation bar

My update query would then equal = b.sub_building_name || ', ' || b.building_name

Without a new column and an index this would take multiple hours

Is there a way to achieve this without creating new concatenation columns?

Comment: What actually are you trying to do ? Do you want to speed up an update query using this index, or ordinary SELECT query ? Please show the SQL query to be optimized using this index.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For an expression based index, you need to put the expression between parentheses:

```
CREATE INDEX matchingcol_idx  
   ON tableB USING btree ( (sub_building_name || ', ' || building_name) );
```

But that index will **only**  be used if you use **exactly** the same condition in your `where` clause. Any condition only referencing one of the columns will not use that index.

Comment: So any other matching I do will need me to create a new index. It definitely worked in a few minutes rather than a few hours, thanks!

Comment: @Luffydude: maybe a multi-column index on `(sub_building_name, building_name)` is the better choice then. But without your query and the complete table definition this is impossible to answer

Comment: thing is, in order to match strings I will need to do some monkey business with substrings and lefts and uppers and commas and no commas in between so I'm not sure. I had to write at least 18 different update statements and it only got me 95% of strings lol

Comment: @Luffydude: again: without the query this is impossible to answer. You should ask a new question that shows some sample data and what you want to do with that data.

Answer (score 0):

For matching via LIKE or ILIKE you can create a `gin` index as described here
https://niallburkley.com/blog/index-columns-for-like-in-postgres/

```sql
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_match_building 
   ON tableB USING gin ( (sub_building_name || ', ' || building_name) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Verify that the extension is enabled via this query

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_extension where extname = 'pg_trgm';
+-------+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| oid   | extname | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion | extconfig | extcondition |
|-------+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------|
| 17458 | pg_trgm | 10       | 17455        | True           | 1.3        | <null>    | <null>       |
+-------+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Relevant info about why `concat` will not cut it :)
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1409893231867-5817884.post%40n5.nabble.com